# Javascript: reference variable in an array within same namespace

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, namespaces

I have the following namespace,

```
var app = {
w: 200,
h: 200,
spacing: 5,
dataList:[
    // 1st column
    [1 * this.w, 1 * this.h, 0 * this.w, 0 * this.h, 'bedroom.jpg', 'Bedroom 1'],
    [1 * this.w, 1 * this.h, 0 * this.w, 1 * this.h, 'topFloorLounge.jpg', 'Top floor lounge'],
    [1 * this.w, 1 * this.h, 0 * this.w, 2 * this.h, 'garage.jpg', 'Garage'],
    // 2nd column
    [2 * this.w, 2 * this.h, 1 * this.w, 0 * this.h, 'livingRoom2.jpg', 'Living room 2'],
    [1 * this.w, 1 * this.h, 1 * this.w, 2 * this.h, 'gym.jpg', 'Gym']
]}
```

but when I console log my dataList, the result for the dataList[0] is`: 
0: NaN
1: NaN
2: NaN
3: NaN
4: "bedroom.jpg"
5: "Bedroom 1"`

obviously, 'this.w' within the array is not referring to w:200 in the same namespace, what have I done wrong? any suggestions is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

this.w is not yet a property, you need 2 steps:

```
var app = {
    w: 200,
    h: 200,
    spacing: 5,
    dataList:[]
};

app.dataList.push(
    // 1st column
    [1 * app.w, 1 * app.h, 0 * app.w, 0 * app.h, 'bedroom.jpg', 'Bedroom 1'],
    [1 * app.w, 1 * app.h, 0 * app.w, 1 * app.h, 'topFloorLounge.jpg', 'Top floor lounge'],
    [1 * app.w, 1 * app.h, 0 * app.w, 2 * app.h, 'garage.jpg', 'Garage'],
    // 2nd column
    [2 * app.w, 2 * app.h, 1 * app.w, 0 * app.h, 'livingRoom2.jpg', 'Living room 2'],
    [1 * app.w, 1 * app.h, 1 * app.w, 2 * app.h, 'gym.jpg', 'Gym']
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executed in global context. This means `this` will refer to `window` object. If you want `this` refer to `app` object, you need to execute the code within its own methods.

```js
var app = {
  w: 200,
  h: 200,
  spacing: 5,
  dataList: function() {
    return [
      // 1st column
      [1 * this.w, 1 * this.h, 0 * this.w, 0 * this.h, 'bedroom.jpg', 'Bedroom 1'],
      [1 * this.w, 1 * this.h, 0 * this.w, 1 * this.h, 'topFloorLounge.jpg', 'Top floor lounge'],
      [1 * this.w, 1 * this.h, 0 * this.w, 2 * this.h, 'garage.jpg', 'Garage'],
      // 2nd column
      [2 * this.w, 2 * this.h, 1 * this.w, 0 * this.h, 'livingRoom2.jpg', 'Living room 2'],
      [1 * this.w, 1 * this.h, 1 * this.w, 2 * this.h, 'gym.jpg', 'Gym']
    ];
  }
};
app.dataList();
```

Comment: thank you, your answer suits my need more as its more self contained and is closer to my originally intended.